# Нет подключения Sql Developer

Tags: база-данных, oracle, sqldeveloper

Я пытаюсь поставить БД Оракла по инструкции указанной на данном сайте: https://datmt.com/backend/how-to-install-oracle-database-on-docker/

Установка прошла успешно, сделал пулл, запустил контейнер. В логах написано, что БД готова к использованию, пользователя создал. Хочу подключиться через SQL Developer,но выводится ошибка:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Ошибка ввода/вывода: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=faQrAZkhQgWkecwsUCTdHQ==)
```

Делал все по инструкции точь-в-точь, не понимаю, в чем проблема. Я бы глянул логи, но не знаю, где они  хранятся для SQL Developer.

Comment: начните с тнспинг

Comment: порт у докера узнали (который ремапится на 1521)?

Comment: Оказывается на сайте было неправильно указаны данные. Я поставил hostname "localhost" и service name "ORCLCDB"(а не ORCLCDB.localdomain). В итоге подключение прошло успешно